# Hide & show checkboxes, lables & parent <p> tags on click

Tags: jquery

I need to hide the p tags but I cannot alter the HTML, so I am trying to use jQuery to work with the elements.  I can get the checkboxes & labels to hide, but cannot collapse the P tags, leaving a gap. Using the control checkbox, how do  I collapse hide the parent p tags of the groups to collapse the gap?

Thanks!

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
        $('#list_31660').change(function () { // listener
        $("#list_31420").toggle(this.checked); // action
        $("label[for='list_31420']").toggle(this.checked);
        $("#list_31656").toggle(this.checked); // action
        $("label[for='list_31656']").toggle(this.checked);

    }).change();
});
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="">
  <p class="form-field email-pref pd-checkbox     %%form-field-dependency-css%%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" id="list_31660" value="31660" />
    &nbsp;
    <label class="inline" for="list_31660">Control Checkbox</label>
  </p>

  <p class="form-field email-pref pd-checkbox     %%form-field-dependency-css%%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" id="list_31656" value="31656" />
       &nbsp;
    <label class="inline" for="list_31656">Hide Show 1</label>
  </p>

  <p class="form-field email-pref pd-checkbox     %%form-field-dependency-css%%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" id="list_31420" value="31420"  />
    &nbsp;
    <label class="inline" for="list_31420">Hide Show 2</label>
  </p>

  <p class="form-field email-pref pd-checkbox     %%form-field-dependency-css%%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" id="list_31662" value="31662" />
    &nbsp;
    <label class="inline" for="list_31662">Another Option</label>
  </p>

</form>
```

Comment: Try `$(this).closest('p').hide()` inside your listener.

Comment: Thanks - and sorry, i a newbie here w/o much JS experience and don't know where to put that.  Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwfyz5rg/

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do?  When you check the box what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Is this how you want it to work?  https://jsfiddle.net/x57ysr3L/

Comment: Sorry - I need the p tags to be hidden on the 2 hide/show options if the control checkbox isn't checked.  updated fiddle to show: https://jsfiddle.net/jwfyz5rg/1/

Comment: Yes!! ^^ Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hiding the `checkbox` and `label` you need to target the `p`.  You can use the `.parent()` function or the `.closest('p')`.  Using `.parent` is better in this case but `.closest` is a little more versatile.  Try this:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#list_31660').change(function () { // listener
    $("#list_31420").parent().toggle(this.checked); // action
    $("#list_31656").parent().toggle(this.checked); // action

}).change();
```

Documentation:

https://api.jquery.com/parent/#parent-selector

https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector